# Modal image using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a modal image so that when you click on the image it opens the image bigger in a pop up.

The code I have (see below) only allows me to open only one image in a pop up. it does not allow me to open the rest of the images,

HTML

```
<section id="responsive">
    <div class="container">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <h2 class="os-animation" data-os-animation="zoomIn" data-os-animation-delay="0.3s">HOW DOES IT WORK</h2>
                        <p style="text-align: left">Exam Portal, enhanced with QFrency SA voices, provides educators with a Quick and Easy to use solution saving them time recording audio, saving parents and schools money hiring Human readers, and enabling learners to bridge a gap where there is nepotism, and an unfair advantage under already stressful testing conditions.</p>
                <video  class="innerfour os-animation" data-os-animation="zoomInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0.6s" width="50%" height="auto" controls>
                    <source src="Videos/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>        <br>                        
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                                <div class="testimonial-content">
                                <h2 style="color:#37cdff" class="feature-content-title blue-text"><span class="blue">1</span>Drag & Drop exam</h2>  
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="myImg" src="img/Link Students.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" >
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <!-- The Close Button -->
                    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                    <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="feature-content-description">Capture an exam quickly by using the Drag & Drop functionality. The user would drag the exam and drop it in the 
                    upload section. The exam will get displayed and it will keep it's original formatting.</p>  
                                <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="testimonial-content">
                    <h2 style="color:#37cdff" class="feature-content-title blue-text"><span class="blue">1</span>Drag & Drop exam</h2>  
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="myImg" src="img/Link Students.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" >
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <!-- The Close Button -->
                    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                    <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="feature-content-description">Capture an exam quickly by using the Drag & Drop functionality. The user would drag the exam and drop it in the 
                    upload section. The exam will get displayed and it will keep it's original formatting.</p>  
                                <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>




                        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Please assists. Thank you

Comment: do not use duplicate `id` use `class` instead. `id` must be unique

Comment: I thought so. Thank you Sir!!

Comment: Still seems to be a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tech2017 suggested, you can use a class instead of repeating the ID which is invalid. Use `getElementsByClassName()` to get a list of all elements with the same class, then loop through the list and assign the `onclick` to a function that has your code. You only need one `myModal`. Here is the code fixed:

```js
function enlargeImage() {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = this.src;
  document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = this.alt;
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

(function() {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = enlargeImage;
  }
})();
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  color: #fff;
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section id="responsive">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h2 class="os-animation" data-os-animation="zoomIn" data-os-animation-delay="0.3s">HOW DOES IT WORK</h2>
      <p style="text-align: left">Exam Portal, enhanced with QFrency SA voices, provides educators with a Quick and Easy to use solution saving them time recording audio, saving parents and schools money hiring Human readers, and enabling learners to bridge a gap where there is
        nepotism, and an unfair advantage under already stressful testing conditions.</p>
      <video class="innerfour os-animation" data-os-animation="zoomInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0.6s" width="50%" height="auto" controls>
         <source src="Videos/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video> <br>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
        <div class="testimonial-content">
          <h2 style="color:#37cdff" class="feature-content-title blue-text"><span class="blue">1</span>Drag & Drop exam</h2>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <!-- The Close Button -->
            <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
            <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
            <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
          <img class="img-responsive myImg" src="img/Link Students.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
          <p class="feature-content-description">Capture an exam quickly by using the Drag & Drop functionality. The user would drag the exam and drop it in the upload section. The exam will get displayed and it will keep it's original formatting.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
        <div class="testimonial-content">
          <h2 style="color:#37cdff" class="feature-content-title blue-text"><span class="blue">1</span>Drag & Drop exam</h2>
          <img class="img-responsive myImg" src="img/Link Students.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
          <p class="feature-content-description">Capture an exam quickly by using the Drag & Drop functionality. The user would drag the exam and drop it in the upload section. The exam will get displayed and it will keep it's original formatting.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!! This worked 100% I really appreciate your help